# Calling methods inside Constructor

Tags: java

Below I am Having Two classes.Parent and Child. The Child class inherits from Parent class .In Parent class constructor I am calling print() method of Parent class.

When I create Object for Child class in main() method the Parent class constructor runs and the Child class print() method is called instead of Parent class print() method.

Q1. Why this Happens.

Q2. Why the value of i is 0

```
public class Sample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Child objChild = new Child();
        objChild.print();
    }
}

class Parent
{   
    void print()
    {
        System.out.println("i Value");
    }

    Parent()
    {
        print();
    }
}    

class Child extends Parent
{
    int i = 45;

    void print()
    {
        System.out.println("i Value = "+i);
    }
}
```

OP

```
i Value = 0
i Value = 45
```

Comment: If I replaced print() with this.print() in Parent constructor why doesn't it print "i Value"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason the child method is called is because virtual method dispatch is the norm in Java. When you call the method, it decides which method to actually call at runtime based on the actual type of the object.

As for why it prints 0, that's because `i` hasn't been set to 45 yet. Each field is initialized with a default value for that type, `0` in the case of integers. When you write `int i = 45`, the compiler will generate code in the constructor to set `i = 45`. But it places this code *after* the parent constructor is called. Therefore, you're printing the variable before it is initialized with its intended value.

Comment: Thanks for Reply The only thing I am still not clear is The code in the Parent Class Constructor first get evaluated before any code in child child gets done.In such a case when the call to print() method  is made in constructor the code in child class would not be available in parent class constructor right. Plz correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 10):

Java actually has some pretty clear rules about this.  Essentially the "int i = 45" code in the subclass is an implicit part of the subclass constructor and the superclass constructor **always** runs first.

The order of events is:

- Create the object and zero out all instance variables.
- Invoke superclass initializers.
- Invoke superclass constructor.
- Invoke subclass initializers (int i = 45; in this example)
- Invoke subclass constructor.

This gets really nasty when you have a final field.  You could declare "i" final in your example and get the same result!

In general, invoking non-private (or at least non-final) methods in a constructor is asking for trouble and is often the source of nasty bugs.  Invoking an abstract method is a **really** bad idea (most of the time).

Comment: You missed a hidden step. In the case of inner classes, the hidden reference to the containing class will be assigned before the superclass constructor is called. Also, superclass initializers are part of the superclass constructor, and should really be listed afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

**Java Beginner** : I got your problem..
1.When you create the object of child class at that time print() method called only in child class not in parent class even though parent class constructor called first bcoz the object is of child class
Please refer the following example.

```
public class Test
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            //create the object of child class
            Child child = new Child();
        }
    }

    class Parent
    {   
        void print()
        {
            System.out.println("parent>> i ValueOne=");
        }

        Parent()
        {
            System.out.println("parent>> i ValueTwo=");
            print();
        }
    }    

    class Child extends Parent
    {
        int i = 45;


        void print()
        {
            System.out.println("Child>>i Value = "+i);
        }
    }
```

**output**:

```
parent>> i ValueTwo=
Child>>i Value = 0
```

2.If you create the parent class object at that time the print() method in parent class is called.
Please refer the following example.

```
public class Test
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            //create the object of Parent class
            Parent parent = new Parent();
        }
    }

    class Parent
    {   
        void print()
        {
            System.out.println("parent>> i ValueOne=");
        }

        Parent()
        {
            System.out.println("parent>> i ValueTwo=");
            print();
        }
    }    

    class Child extends Parent
    {
        int i = 45;


        void print()
        {
            System.out.println("Child>>i Value = "+i);
        }
    }
```

**output**:

```
parent>> i ValueTwo=
parent>> i ValueOne=
```

3.And i think you have already cleared why that value of i is 0 or 45.

Answer (score 2):

Because at that time of first call to print method `i` is not initialized to 45 so its printing 0.

call goes like this

- child constructor (as because of constructor chaining from child to parent)
- parent constructor
- print method (now here `i` is not initialized coz child constructor is not complete yet so its printing the default value of `i` which is 0 )
- now after completion of parent constructor and then child constructor `i` gets its value which is 45 -
- so now it prints 45 on the next call of print method

Comment: You're still using "coz". Chat speak is not helpful for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

First, I do not see the constructor definition in your `Child` class.

When you do not define a constructor for a `Child` class, its default constructor is:

```
public Child() {
    super();
}
```

Where `super();` calls the `Parent` class constructor(super class constructor).

However, you defined your `print()` method in `Child` class, and since it has the same signature(name+parameter) as the method in `Parent` class, it overrides its super class method with the same signature.

That is why your `Child` class calls `Parent` class constructor, while it calls its own `print()` method.

-added:

The first i value is 0 because you did not initialize an int variable `i` in `Parent` class, and the value of an uninitialized int variable is 0 by default. After `Parent` is called, it invokes now `Child`'s `print()` method, and `i` is initialized in `Child` class, so now `i` is the value you initialized

Comment: To OP: 'Thanks for Reply The only thing I am still not clear is The code in the Parent Class Constructor first get evaluated before any code in child child gets done.'  --> You should define a Child class constructor manually.

Comment: There's no need to define a constructor manually if the default constructor does what you want. The issue here is orthogonal - you're breaking a common convention in Java by calling an overridden method in the superclass constructor. Since this opens you to unexpected behavior, it's usually discouraged.

Comment: @Antimony: I guess when OP said 'When I create Object for Child Class the Parent Class Constructor runs', he is saying the default constructor is not doing what he is want.

Answer (score 1):

Your child first calls your parent's constructor. At this point, i isn't initialized with the 45 value. That's why it prints 0 (the default int value).